# why is my console displaying my result as numbers insteadof the actual string in my array in the code below

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, integer, console.log

```js
var arrayNames = ["Angela", "Ben", "Jenny", "Michael", "Chloe"];

function whosPaying(names) {
  var bigBoss = arrayNames.length;
  var ogaMi = Math.floor((Math.random() * bigBoss));

  return ogaMi + " is paying for the bill"
}

console.log(whosPaying());
```

Comment: Because you are using `ogaMi` which is the randomly generated number. You should use that number as the index of the array.

Comment: Because you use the size of your array, your bigbos variable therefore corresponds to 4

Comment: as a side note it usually helps to use meaningful names in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you just get the index,not the element itself

so change

```
 var ogaMi = Math.floor((Math.random() * bigBoss));
```

to

```
 var ogaMi = arrayNames[Math.floor((Math.random() * bigBoss))];
```

```js
var arrayNames = ["Angela", "Ben", "Jenny", "Michael", "Chloe"];

function whosPaying(names) {
  var bigBoss = arrayNames.length;
  var ogaMi = arrayNames[Math.floor((Math.random() * bigBoss))];

  return ogaMi + " is paying for the bill"
}

console.log(whosPaying());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `ogaMi` with `arrayNames[ogaMi]`.

```js
var arrayNames = ["Angela", "Ben", "Jenny", "Michael", "Chloe"];

function whosPaying(names) {
  var bigBoss = arrayNames.length;
  var ogaMi = Math.floor((Math.random() * bigBoss));

  return arrayNames[ogaMi] + " is paying for the bill"
}

console.log(whosPaying());
```